# Laravel - after date validation with date from rules set

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to validate two dates to ensure one is greater than the other using the `after` validate rule. I have my rules set like this:

```
$rules = array(
 'date_from' => 'required|date_format:"d/m/Y"', 
 'date_to'   => 'required|date_format:"d/m/Y"|after:date_from',
 // more rules ...
);
```

When using the following values:
`date_from` = "01/06/2014" and `date_to` = "01/06/2014" OR `date_to` = "12/06/2014" everything is hunky dory, however.. using anything above 12 for day fails i.e. `date_to` = "13/06/2014" to `date_to` = "31/06/2014"

I've also tried this and it gives the same results:

```
$dateFromForm = Input::get('date_from');

$rules = array(
 'date_from'  => 'required|date_format:"d/m/Y"', 
 'date_to'    => 'required|date_format:"d/m/Y"|after:' . $dateFromForm,
);
```

Quite clearly to me it's reading the day as the month, any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the Laravel docs - it says

> The dates will be passed into the PHP strtotime function.

The problem with `strtotime` is that it assumes you are using `m/d/Y`. If you want `d/m/Y` - you need to change it to `d-m-Y` to be correctly parsed.

So change your date format to `d-m-Y` and it will work.

Comment: Worked right away, thanks a lot! Will accept the answer when SO lets me :D